# How do I make the add to cart button go straight to cart

Tags: javascript, shopping-cart

I am trying to edit the 'add to cart' button for the site I am customizing http://radiantiger.bigcartel.com/product/hhhgtf. I want the customer to click on the 'add to cart' button and be taken straight to the cart.

1) I understand I have to edit the javascript for the add to cart button, How do I do that? & what code should I use?

2) how do I move the 'cart button' from the top left of the sidebar and make it inline with my 'add to cart button' like this: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/90031565/Fullscreen%20capture%20382013%2050354%20PM.jpg

I tried putting the "cart button" into the same div with the "add to cart button", but it lost the realtime display of whats in the cart functionality.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the cart_nav_list from the aside bar and into the ID add_cart.

So for example your code should look like this:

```
<div id="add_cart">
 <button class="button" type="submit" name="submit" id="add_to_cart">Add to Cart</button>
  <ul class="clearfix" id="cart_nav_list">
   <li id="cart_button">
    <a id="open_cart" href="/cart">Cart
     <div class="clearfix" id="cart_info">
      <span id="cart_count">0</span>
      <span id="cart_divider">|</span>
      <span id="cart_total"><span class="currency_sign">$</span>0.00</span>
     </div>
    </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Attached a screenshot to display more information where you find these elements. To see information like I've pasted install firebug.

[html5 move cart rightside http://www.bybe.net/downloads/html5-move-cart-rightside.png](http://www.bybe.net/downloads/html5-move-cart-rightside.png)

Additionally to get the the elements working side by side your need to make a minor edition to the style sheet like so:

```
#add_cart button, #cart_nav_list {
 float:left;
}
```